# Celery shared_task parameters wrong parsing

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

i'm using celery 4.2.0 with Django to schedule new tasks in rabbitmq and it randomly fails when it comes to parse arguments. 
My code looks like that:

```
for param in serializer.validated_data['parameters']:
        run_task.delay(param_name=param)
```

Where parameters is list of int and it is ensured with serializer validation.

```
@shared_task
def run_task(param_name: int) -> None:
    obj= Obj.objects.filter(param=param_name)
    ...
```

Under UTs when i invoke this `run_task` with `CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER=True` everything works. On real enviroment this tasks sometimes runs just OK and sometimes it fails with server error:

```
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py", line 53, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/app/compliance/jobs/views.py", line 30, in create_task
    run_task.delay(param_name=param)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 408, in delay
    return self.apply_async(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 535, in apply_async
    **options
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 741, in send_task
    with self.producer_or_acquire(producer) as P:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 876, in producer_or_acquire
    producer, self.producer_pool.acquire, block=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 1246, in producer_pool
    return self.amqp.producer_pool
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py", line 612, in producer_pool
    self.app.connection_for_write()]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/collections.py", line 34, in __getitem__
    h = eqhash(key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/collections.py", line 25, in eqhash
    return o.__eqhash__()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 629, in __eqhash__
    repr(self.transport_options))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/collections.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.hashvalue = hash(seq)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

I understand error itself but how come it appears here when I pass only one simple and parsable argument - not set. Does anyone know how to make it work persistently? 
Thanks!

Comment: Can you print the value of `param` in the failing cases?

Comment: Just line before sending i have: `LOGGER.info('Sending request for param %d', param)` and it produces `Sending request for param 17`